# Return last rows from specific row

Tags: sqlite, select

I'm trying to return the rows that come after a specific row:

```
ID      Title
1       "Title 1"
2       "Title 2"
3       "Title 3"
4       "Title 4"
5       "Title 5"
6       "Title 6"
7       "Title 7"
8       Title 8
9       Title 9
10      Title 10
```

So, given ID of 5, I'd like to return rows 6,7,8,9,10

This is what I've tried, so far:
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY ID ASC;

Comment: Are the ID values reliably ordered?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that, on they aren't auto-incremented

Comment: How do you define the ordering to know what comes after a given row?

Comment: I did not ask about the special case "auto-increment", I asked about the more generic case of being always ordered, which includes gaps. I.e. the order you use as the foundation for the "after a specific row". I.e. if a row in your database is to be part of the output, then it will have an Id which is larger than the Id of the reference row. If this is NOT the case then please show more examples which do not match this. Also show more examples in which the rows have non-consecutive Ids, which I assume there must be, since you describe them as not auto-incremented.

Comment: Please give the examples in the shape of a [mcve], i.e. some lines of "create table..." and "insert...". Use the `.dump` feature of sqlites commandline tool.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more information inside your question (e.g. to provide an MCVE).

Answer (score 1):

If your IDs are always incrementing you can use the following:

`SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ID > [number]`

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that, on they aren't auto-incremented

Comment: Kris B, auto-incrementation is not required for this to work. Order is sufficient. If this does not work then please give a MCVE with an example in which this does NOT work. Without that explanation, your question is unclear, which severely cripples the chances for a satisfying answer.